# How to get all indices of output array in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm gathering info on SSL certs on servers (looking for expiration date) using the `find` module.

```
- name: Find certs on server
  find:
    path: /etc/ssl/custom/certs
    file_type: file
    patterns: "*.crt"
    recurse: yes
  register: find_result
- debug:
    var: find_result
```

The results are:

```
ok: [server00] => {
    "find_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 5,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1622749788.1552677,
                "ctime": 1622744497.4393551,
                "dev": 2050,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 19531534,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1622744497.4393551,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/etc/ssl/custom/certs/somewebsite0.com.crt",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 1879,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            {
                "atime": 1622719627.2477663,
                "ctime": 1616545902.3681087,
                "dev": 2050,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 19531253,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1613754568.0,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/etc/ssl/custom/certs/somewebsite1.com.crt",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 2081,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            {
                "atime": 1622719627.2197664,
                "ctime": 1616545902.3721087,
                "dev": 2050,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 19535012,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1601653231.0,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/etc/ssl/custom/certs/somewebsite2.com.crt",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 2269,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            }
        ],
        "matched": 3,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

I'm needing the `path` portion of the output (`"path": "/etc/ssl/custom/certs/somewebsite1.com.crt"`), and if I use `find_result.files[0].path` it only gives me a single result for each host, when I need every `*.crt` file.

How can I access each index? I try to use the `shell` module to perform an action on the `.crt` file, but again, it's only grabbing the first one due to the `[0]` index, like so:

```
- name: Check expiration
  shell: "cat {{ find_result.files[0].path }} | openssl x509 -noout -enddate"
  register: date
- debug:
    var: date.stdout_lines

ok: [server00] => {
    "date.stdout_lines": [
        "notAfter=Apr  2 19:50:38 2018 GMT"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html), and more specifically on `find_result.files`.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax for looping over what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be an example playbook based on it:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Find certs on server
      find:
       path: /etc/ssl/custom/certs
       file_type: file
       patterns: "*.crt"
       recurse: yes
      register: find_result
    - debug:
       var: find_result

    - name: Play with the data just to demonstrate
      set_fact: 
        IRGeekSauce_list: "{{ (IRGeekSauce_list|default([])) + [item.path] }}"# <-- add each list item to a custom list
      with_items: '{{ find_result.files }}' # <-- here we get the files as a list.
    
    - name: your list
      debug:
       msg: '{{ IRGeekSauce_list }}'

    - include_tasks: anothertasklist.yml
      loop: '{{ IRGeekSauce_list }}'
      loop_control:
        loop_var: singlepathvariable
```

And then you have another "playbook" with just the tasks 'anothertasklist.yml'

```
 - name: hello
   debug:
    msg: 'You are now in another playbook'

 - name:
   debug:
    msg: 'Woho: {{ singlepathvariable }}'

 - name:
   openssl_certificate_info:
    howeverthatmoduleworks...
```

And you should be able to just take the entire and include find_result.files as the loop, and then instead just use the loopvar singlepathvariable(and maybe rename it) and just take out the path as {{ singlepathvariable.path }}

Comment: That helps tremendously, but what is the `default([])` portion mean where you concatenate the `item.path`?

Comment: This doesn't completely answer my question, since I don't want another playbook, and it doesn't show me how to access the list in the expiration check. For example, openssl_certificate uses `path`, but I don't know how to define the path since there are going to be more than one (need a loop). So what would be the placeholder for path?

Comment: @IRGreekSause 1.)defaul([]) defines the variable as a list - if it is not defined before.  2.) include_task(so a list of other tasks to perform) and I think this is the easiest way if you are going to do alot of stuff with it. I am not sure if I understand you correctly but you just want to locate all .crt files, and run a shell script to check expiration date on them and this you just want printed out. You should be able to just run the shell command with `shell: openssl mumbojumbo {{ item.path  }} -enddate` and `with_items: find_result.files`(see my with_item). But I would want to loop it.